# rememberMe occurs randomly without fiddler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

ASP.net MVC 3 out of the box forms authentication

when certain users on certain browsers try and authenticate they get the following error

Server Error in '/MVC' Application.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'rememberMe' of 
    non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
   LogOn(System.String,
   System.String, Boolean, System.String)' in 'RipsMVC.Controllers.AccountController'. An 
   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
   optional parameter.

Parameter name: parameters

the problem is its not all the time but whenever i turn on fiddler2 it automatically works so i have no clue what the root cause is .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it related to fiddler, maybe you need to make `rememberMe` with `[DefaultValue(false)]` or make it a `bool?`.

Anyway, you can setup a breakpoint and check the request body (using `Request.Forms`) to see the difference with/without fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Is remember me a checkbox on the form? HTML says that checkbox values are only submitted if they are checked. So if it is unchecked, you need to send a hidden field with a false value. Using MVC `@Html.CheckBox` should do this automatically. However, if your HTML just renders out a single checkbox, then it might not be submitted to get a false value on the server.